# Which small audio recording devices are appropriate for terrestrial biologging tags?

Tags: recording, biologging

I am interested to know which small (<3 x 2 cm board size) audio recording devices people have been using for on-animal acoustic tags (terrestrial) and what have been everyone’s experiences with them in terms of reliability, useful features, and drawbacks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about other products, but we do have designed our own logger with audio/accelero/magnetometry, optimized for extremely low-power consumption. We have many current deployments different species of large or medium-sized mammals (from lions to lynx, although we still have to adjust our casing for the smallest species). We don't have a website yet so please contact me for details.

simon chamaillé-jammes

Answer (score 3):

Not used them myself, but the Audiomoth µmoth will be of interest to you:  https://www.openacousticdevices.info/audiomoth

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From my experience and understanding, most folks doing on-board recordings at that size (myself included) use custom built tags. I did purchase some Audiomoth µmoth but haven't had a chance to test them out.

Depending on your species of interest, the most important consideration is likely going to be weight, not size. Weight will be a combination of the components, as well as battery. Ideally you'd want to have just enough power for your needs, as any extra will just be unwanted weight. Also, do you need your units to be weatherproof (any cases will add weight) or can you leave the components relatively exposed?

The second consideration is how you will recover the tags. If it's for long-term deployment, you need a reliable way to locate the tags.

From an acoustics perspective, another consideration is whether you need your microphone calibrated or not, and conducting calibration if your sensor isn't pre-calibrated.

The great news is that acoustic/behavioral tags and technologies are getting more and more miniaturized, so I wouldn't be surprised if we see more all-in-one solutions for biologists in the next few years.